# Rasa NLU never returns fallback intent

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I was experimenting with the NLU parts of Rasa. In my config.yml I have a Fallback Policy with a 70% threshold.

When I either run a server or try the NLU only shell, I never get a Fallback Intent on the response even if the confidence is way below 70%. It does not make sense for the NLU only mode to use the Fallback policy, so I understand why this might happen.

But I am migrating from Dialogflow, so I would like the NLU response to return a Fallback Intent if the sent message does not fall under any defined intent. How may I do this?

Alternatively, if it is possible to get the NLU data along with the Core's response, that would also work.

N.B: I am using `rasa 1.10.3` and `rasa-sdk 1.10.1`

Here's the `config.yml` file, I'm mostly using the default settings generated by `rasa init`,

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: en
pipeline:
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
  - name: RegexFeaturizer
  - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: "char_wb"
    min_ngram: 1
    max_ngram: 4
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 100
  - name: EntitySynonymMapper
    epochs: 100

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MappingPolicy
  - name: "FallbackPolicy"
    nlu_threshold: 0.7
    core_threshold: 0.7
    fallback_action_name: "utter_Default Fallback Intent"
```

Comment: Did you find a way for defining a fallback intent? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the tracker inside core should have all the information about which intent was triggered with what confidence. So if you are using the capabilities of core as well then you can make use of the tracker. Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was posted long ago with a different Rasa Core version I am going to answer it for version 3.5.0.

I have put my fallback in the **pipeline** instead of the **policies** inside of the `config.yml`.

```
- name: FallbackClassifier
  threshold: 0.9
  ambiguity_threshold: 0.1
```

Note that the `ambiguity_threshold` configures the fallback to be triggered when the confidence of two intents differs below the given number.